# what is the best online site to post questions on Ektron?

Tags: ektron

I am trying to do a new project in Ektron with Dotnet. I see that there are quite a less
 questions posted and the responses for them in stackoverflow. What would be the best site 
 to get my doubts cleared when doing the development using Ektron. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here at stackoverflow and https://developer.ektron.com/Forums/ are the best resources I have found.

Answer (score 9):

(Agree with zkent, but with an additional recommendation) Post to either the Ektron Dev Center (dev.ektron.com) or stackoverflow, then tweet the link to twitter including the hashtag #ektron. A tweet might look something like "I just posted a question about [foo] to SO/DevCenter [link] #ektron" There are a lot of helpful ektron developers watching the twitter stream, so it's a great way to reach out.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I had not thought of that.

Comment: Worked for me, egandalf replied on twitter almost at once TQ :)

Answer (score 0):

The Ektron Dev Center is now at http://developer.ektron.com.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Ektron's Customer Portal as well that has a knowledge base of known issues.

https://portal.ektron.com/knowledgebase